# What does "what lies ahead" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

*Firstly sorry for my bad English.*

I'm translating an [article](http://www.phonearena.com/news/To-wearable-or-not-to-wearable_id64018) about wearable smart watches. But what does `what lies ahead` mean in the following context?

> There is no shortage of wearable gear out there, and really what I’m
>   writing about here is the latest crop of smartwatches, most of which
>   run on Android Wear. In the grand scheme, I know it is but a portion
>   of what many of us may use, be it Jawbone’s UP, or Fitbit, or
>   Samsung’s Tizen powered Galaxy Gear, and for me, it really comes down
>   to a single issue. As I thought about that single issue though, I
>   examined other factors that leave me feeling pensive about **what lies
>   ahead**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"what lies ahead" is a term that means "in the future." It is primarily used for figurative things like social implications, technological advancement, or other general "future stuff" -- but if you're on a road trip, it may indeed include more literal things like mountains, rivers, swamps, cities, etc., that you will need to navigate through.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those questions that would vex a learner if you tried to parse *lies ahead* as two words instead of one phrase.

Apparently, it's only listed in a [couple dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=lie+ahead&ls=a). NOAD simply defines it as:

> **lie ahead** (*phrasal verb*) be going to happen; be in store : *I'm excited by what lies ahead*.

However, Macmillan's definition suggests it can be used in somewhat ominous situations, as a way of foreshadowing difficult circumstances on the horizon:

> **lie ahead** (*phrasal verb*) if something lies ahead, especially something difficult or unpleasant, it is going to happen in the future and you will have to deal with it

In the usage you quote, though, I think *pensive* is a more neutral word, not one that conveys uneasiness.

Comment: These usages are similar to the phrases "the road ahead" and "[The Road to Serfdom](http://www.barefootsworld.net/serfdom.html)".